# Multiple Inner Joins Group By 'not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I keep getting the below error when trying to do a Group By on Multiple Inner Joins.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'address.Address1' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Below is my code, can't work out what I am doing wrong.

```
select Ad.Address1, Ad.Address2, Ad.PostalCode, Tw.Town, Co.County, CI.InstallationName,C.CompanyName
FROM address as AD

Inner Join 
(Select TownId, Town From
Town as Tw)TW 
ON Tw.TownID=Ad.TownID

Inner Join
(select County, CountyID From
County as CO) CO
ON CO.countyid=Ad.CountyID

Inner Join
(select ClientID, InstallationName, AddressID From
ClientInstallations as CI) CI
ON CI.AddressID=Ad.AddressID

Inner Join
(select ClientID, CompanyName From
Client as C) C
ON C.ClientID=CI.ClientID

Where Address1 <> '' and Address2 <> '' and PostalCode <> '' and Town <> '' and County is not null
Group By CompanyName
```

Apologies for the messy code, just started learning this stuff so would appreciate some tips.

Many Thanks
Sam

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: If a `GROUP BY` clause is specified, each column reference in the `SELECT` list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query SQL server - " is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234686/query-sql-server-is-not-contained-in-either-an-aggregate-function-or-the-gro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I understand from your comment is all you want is how many records of the same company name exist. If that’s the case then you can rewrite the query as:

```
select COUNT(*),
       C.CompanyName
FROM [address] as AD
Inner Join 
(Select TownId, Town FROM Town as Tw)TW 
ON Tw.TownID=Ad.TownID
Inner Join
(select County, CountyID FROM County as CO) CO
ON CO.countyid=Ad.CountyID
Inner Join
(select ClientID, InstallationName, AddressID From
ClientInstallations as CI) CI
ON CI.AddressID=Ad.AddressID
Inner Join
(select ClientID, CompanyName FROM 
Client as C) C
ON C.ClientID=CI.ClientID
Where Address1 <> '' and Address2 <> '' and PostalCode <> '' and Town <> '' and County is not null
Group By CompanyName
```

Comment: Is it posisble to group by CompanyName & Town?

I need all the address fields in their as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong, is using a `mysql` like script for `sql server`. In sql server (and every other sane DBMS), every selected attribute, which is not in an aggregate function, has to be in the `group by`. In your case, I don't understand why you are using a `group by` at all, since you don't use aggregate functions. So your solution should be to remove the `group by`.

**edit based on comment**

If you only want to count the records for each `companyname`, you should do `select companyname, count(1) cnt from (your selection) group by companyname`. If you want the rest of the attributes as well, you'll have to include them in the `group by`.

Comment: What I want to achieve is how many records of the same company name exist. When I take the Group By out, I have around 850 rows. I would like to reduce that significantly.

Edit: 

Will I have to group by on each select statement then?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check out the list of what you want to extract from the db (the fields after the first 'select') :

```
select Ad.Address1, Ad.Address2, Ad.PostalCode, Tw.Town, Co.County, CI.InstallationName,C.CompanyName
```

however, after doing all your joins, you group by

```
Group By CompanyName
```

you error message is actually just the first error encountered. you shold get the same response for Ad.Address2 then Ad.PostalCode then Tw.Town etc... Co.County, CI.InstallationName if you omit the first field

the rule is - if you select a list of fields, each one should either by in the group by clause or aggregated in some way. 
it does make sense - if you do not aggregate (i.e. - turn multiple values into one - `sum(..), count(..), min(..)` etc) then there are many possible values for this field. either make each combination a new row (group by it) or choose a proper way to get a single value from the possible many ones